# How to import custom object fields in LWC js file

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningjs

I dont find any standard documentation on importing custom object and its field to import in lwc js.

Like how do we even **import custom obect's picklist** and show them on frontend?

Comment: Please check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values
and 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values_record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import references to Salesforce objects and fields from `@salesforce/schema`.

Refer to documentation section [Import References to Salesforce Objects and Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about) :

**To import a reference to an object, use this syntax.**

```
import objectName from '@salesforce/schema/object';
import objectName from '@salesforce/schema/namespace__object';

import POSITION_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Position__c';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
```

**To import a reference to a field, use this syntax.**

```
import FIELD_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/object.field';

import POSITION_LEVEL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Position__c.Level__c';
import ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
```